# how to load an array variable into a div - ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have a `div` like below :

```
<div id="#myid">
if($values){
    echo "<p>$values['one']</p>";
    echo "<p>$values['two']</p>";
}
</div>
```

because my div is big, I would like to send a request to server and load response it into my `div` :

```
$.post('myurl', {target:target} , function(data){
    $('#myid').???(data);
});
```

I don't want to override all content of my `div`. I just want to pass an array(or anything like an array example `json`) variable to my `div`. how can I do?

my `div` content :

```
<div id="product-quick-view-add-to-cart" class="mfp-with-anim mfp-hide mfp-dialog mfp-dialog-big clearfix">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <small><a class="text-muted float-to-right" href="#">$val1</a></small>
            <br />
            <h3 class="float-to-right">$val2</h3>
            <br />
            <br />
            <p class="text-smaller text-muted float-to-right">$val2 </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-allowfullscreen="1" data-thumbheight="50" data-thumbwidth="50">
                <img src="$val3" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Gamer Chick" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <hr class="hr-mt-5-mb-10" />
            <span>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-align-center">
                    <p>$val4</p>
                    <p>$val5</p>
                </div>
            </span>
            <span>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-align-center">
                    <p>$val6</p>
                    <p>$val7</p>
                </div>
            </span>
            <span>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-align-center">
                    <p>val</p>
                    <p>$val8</p>
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">add</a>
</div>
```

Someone suggested to me that I use `angularjs` framewrok. but I don't know that is best solution.

Comment: is response from ajax is html ? the you should use ` $('#myid').html(data);
`

Comment: If return is htl use `$('#myid').html(data);` @S.M_Emamian

Comment: no, it returns an array .

Comment: You can do `for` on your array to get `value` and use `$('#myid').append(data);` on each loop @S.M_Emamian

Comment: NO ! my div is static on my page. I just send an `id `  to server and response value is an array value.

Comment: can you show a sample JSON response? You can iterate through your JSON object and put the values using `$.each(json_response, function() {// target the elements and update .html()})`. BTW, this is `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('myurl', {target:target} , function(data){
```

$('#myid').append(data);
});

it will append the php result on the div without removing previous data

Comment: I don't think OP is looking for `.append()`

Comment: @ Fr0zenFyr  yes. I don't want to use an append function .

Comment: @S.M_Emamian: you will have to use `.each()` and the target individual `div` to either `append()` or `html()` according to your need. post a sample JSON so that you get useful answer.

Comment: you can simplify your array data in your php page 
e.g foreach($users as $items){
<h1></h1>
}
and then append it using ajax